# Unexpected output from python script when called from java

Tags: java, python

I'm working in a java project where I call a python script which generates a json output that I use in my Java code.
The python script works perfectly if I run it from my terminal (CMD). However, when I run it from Java the output is "empty"
When I said empty is not really empty. The values which should associate in json are not being associated. I don't understand why this is happening.

This is the java part

```
public String getPrediccion ()  {
    String ejecutable = "python C:\\Users\\Carlos\\Documents\\GitHub\\AnalyceTiffScript\\src\\prediccionesCompl.py";
    getCoords(ruta);
    //Process pre;
    try {
        Process pre = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ejecutable+" "+latitud+" "+longitud+" "+dia_prediccion);
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pre.getInputStream()));
        
        String res = in.readLine();
        
        System.out.println(res);
        
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jobject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(res);
        
        fecha = (String) jobject.get("fecha");
        presion = (Double) jobject.get("presion");
        tMax = (Double) jobject.get("tmax");
        tMin = (Double) jobject.get("tmin");
        tMedia = (Double) jobject.get("tmedia");
        vel_viento = (Double) jobject.get("viento");
        humedad = (Double) jobject.get("humedad");
        coeficiente = (Double) jobject.get("AsBs");
        
        
        */
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }/* catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The system.out.println (res) is returning

```
 {"fecha": "", "presion": 0.0, "tmax": 0.0, "tmin": 0.0, "tmedia": 0.0, "viento": 0.0, "humedad": 0.0, "AsBs": 0.25}
```

The python script call some functions. This is the main part.

```py
if __name__ =="__main__":
    #Longitud, Latitud, Data =OpenGeoTiffAndGetData(sys.argv[1])
    #Se leen y guardan en variables los 3 datos que necesitamos para un pronostico
    #Latitud, Longitud y dia (0-6)
    Longitud = (sys.argv[1])
    Latitud = (sys.argv[2])
    pos = int(sys.argv[3])

    #Se llama a la funcion que recibe el JSON y este lo guardamos en la variable Data
    Data = getData(Latitud, Longitud)

    DataDates= SeparateDays(Data)
    ListaResultado_Temp_Max= GetMaxTemp(DataDates, Data)
    ListaResultado_Temp_Min= GetMinTemp(DataDates, Data)
    ListaResultado_Temp_Media= GetMediumTemp(DataDates,Data)
    Lista_Resultado_Presion = GetPressure(DataDates, Data)
    Lista_Resultado_WindSpeed = GetWindSpeed(DataDates, Data)
    Lista_Resultado_Humidity = GetHumidity(DataDates, Data)
    Lista_Resultado_Weather = GetWeather(DataDates, Data)
    #ShowResults(ListaResultado_Temp_Max,ListaResultado_Temp_Min, Lista_Resultado_Presion, ListaResultado_Temp_Media)

    #solicitar posicion del array dependiendo del dia 
    #pos = int(input("Sabiendo que puede elegir los 6 próximos dias, indique de qué dia quiere los datos sabiendo que la cuenta empieza en 0 "))
    
    P , dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos,Lista_Resultado_Presion)
    Tmax , dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos,ListaResultado_Temp_Max)
    T, dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos,ListaResultado_Temp_Media)
    Tmin , dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos,ListaResultado_Temp_Min)
    U, dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos,Lista_Resultado_WindSpeed)
    RH, dia = accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos, Lista_Resultado_Humidity)
    Weather, dia =accesElementInAListFromPosition(pos, Lista_Resultado_Weather)

    coef=GetAsBs(Weather)
    #Resultados, se ha añadido un campo fecha y se le da formato json
    #Se hacen los cast necesarios para evitar errores extraños en otros lenguajes

    presion = P
    
    resultado = {
        "fecha": dia,
        "presion": presion,
        "tmax": Tmax, 
        "tmin": Tmin,
        "tmedia": T,
        "viento": U,
        "humedad": RH,
        "AsBs": coef
    }

    resjson = json.dumps(resultado)
    print(resjson)
```

This is the result if I run the script directly from the terminal

```
{"fecha": "2021-01-11", "presion": 1021.0, "tmax": 12.07, "tmin": 7.94, "tmedia": 9.620000000000001, "viento": 1.3225, "humedad": 64.5, "AsBs": 0.5}
```

- Any idea why my script is not storing the results when I called from java?
- What is the difference between calling a script from java and from a terminal?

Comment: Have you checked if any the intermediate results in your Python script are empty when you run it from Java (e.g., `DataDates` and `Data`)?

Comment: I shouldn't have any. Everything is running in memory for now... Everything is initialized as well.